# How to construct a query to include historical data

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and trying to learn by doing some projects. Currently, I have a query that take in start and end date as parameter. The query is filter by breed_type and race_date. I need to make it so that the data for this query include breed_type 1,2, and 3 for race_date > 1/1/2020 and include breed_type 1 and 2 for race_date < 1/1/2021.

Sample Data:

| race_date | breed_type | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/30/2020 | 1 | 20 |
| 12/30/2020 | 2 | 10 |
| 12/30/2020 | 3 | 40 |
| 12/31/2020 | 3 | 10 |
| 12/31/2020 | 2 | 20 |
| 1/1/2021 | 1 | 25 |
| 1/1/2021 | 2 | 20 |
| 1/2/2021 | 1 | 10 |
| 1/2/2021 | 2 | 10 |
| 1/2/2021 | 3 | 20 |

What I currently have:

> SELECT SUM(nvl(sales,0)) sales
> FROM results t
> WHERE t.race_date BETWEEN '12/30/2020' AND '01/02/2021'
> AND breed_type in (1,2,3)

but I want this query to show the sales for breed_type in (1,2) for race_date < 01/01/2021 and only include breed_type 3 for race_date > 01/01/2021.

Expected sales should be: 135

Actual sales: 185

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a tag for the type of sql you're working with, and then also add in your query and explain the results you are getting versus the results you expect to get

Comment: Use two subselects in your where clause and check using the primary key if the tuple is in one of both sets.  So: where PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN(S) in (subselect 1) or PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN(S) in (subselect 2).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean?

```
SELECT SUM(sales)
FROM results
WHERE (breed_type in (1,2) AND race_date < '01/01/2021')
OR (breed_type in (3) AND race_date > '01/01/2021')
```

Be aware that your question excluded `01/01/2021` from both fiters. I assume you would like one of them to be `<=` or `>=`.